# Only first scrollspy is working on my site, no matter what I do second is not responding even with the same structure and different ids

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to ask you for help with bootstrap scollspy. I implemented first one in my project it is working fine and I am happy.

Problems started when I wanted to add another, different ID, different target. I added it in the same way but I cannot get it to work.

I googled about this but I couldn't find solution or proper informations, I saw some posts that there should be only one scrollspy on "body" I tried to experiment with that knowledge but still nothing.

My code:

```
    <div id="back-button">
        <a href="#projects">Back</a>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#back-button' });
    </script>

    <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#projects" data-offset="0">

        CONTENT HERE

    </div>
```

I tried to change order, change IDs to Classes, move scripts around but still nothing. Can you please help me?

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: Did you try with `$('body').scrollspy({target: ''});` ? I think if you don't specify target to scrollSpy, all your navigation links are considered

Comment: Hi, yes I tried that. I tried deleting from second one, then from both of them. Didn't work in both cases.